# Will search engines penalize spam links in Facebook comments for websites?

Tags: seo, facebook, links

I have many static HTML web pages in which I had used Facebook comments. A user had posted a spam link in one of the page's comments. I logged in as a moderator and deleted it, banned the user, and marked it as spam. Yet Facebook displayed the message: `Comments from USERNAME will only be visible to his friends. Undo`. As the message says, it provided an undo link.

The problem is in the future when search engine bots crawl Facebook comments, and if they use the links posted in the comment which lead to spam websites, then I may get a penalty for linking to spam sites.

So how do I remove the comments entirely from Facebook, so that not even the user's friends would see it?

May be if only their friends can see it then search engines cannot crawl it. But if his friends use those links then that might add a link to the target site, which leads to my site being the referral to the span site.

So what should be done?

Comment: Can you clarify the first sentence?

Comment: i have modified the first sentence.

Comment: If you are loading those comments with ajax/js, there is a good chance that search engines won't crawl them in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

Just check whether the nofollow tag is present in those comment links or not. If yes, then search engine ranking will not affect by those comments. If not then you have to worry.

[Click here](http://google.about.com/od/searchengineoptimization/qt/how_to_make_nofollow_tag.htm) for more